# Will one transaction with million of queries blocking?

Tags: migration, transaction, blocking

I am having a data migrating task that need to run couple of million UPDATE queries in one single database transaction. Will this causes anything bad for other clients connecting/querying from the database while my task is running?

Comment: The answer will depend on your DBMS of choice, tables and indexes involved, and the exact SQL statements executed by both your data migration task and other clients. However, based on how your question is phrased, I suspect the likelihood of "anything bad" is pretty high.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you some example of "anything bad" that may happen (given the assumption from common cases or the case you have met)? In what particular setup, there will be "nothing bad" at all? Sorry if my question is vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can not be answered as you say nothing about your infrastructure. Also not your problem - if that is your task, it is the problem of whoever defined this task.

THAT SAID: Last time I did a high performance data migration pump, you can possibly do with a lot less by storing the updated value in temporary staging tables, then do bulk updates into the final data.

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you explain more how infrastructure is a factor here? I'm trying to understand how DB transaction work by "flushing" the whole bunch of million queries and ensure the atomicity of the task. (Trying my best to not falling into XY problem here)

Comment: I was submitting 1 million reuqests PER MINUTE using 96 threads on a 48 core server. This requiers high end database and applciation servers (and network) which most setups will not have. Your server may simply take hours to do that and that will be the problem. Also Oracle has a problem with too large transactions. Other databases have other limits - again, infrastructure. The way you formualte it it gets into academid blabla because it does not take the infrasructure into account. Generally I would also question the need for ONE transaction that spans a million updates.